# Undefined offset 0 but nothing is undefined in var_dump

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm getting a lot of errors with arrays lately and I cant seem to figure this one out at all.

I get the error:

> Undefined offset 0

So of course that means that the index doesn't exist.

Now the next thing I did after this error, I `var_dump` the arrays.

First I'll show you some code:

```
var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
   var_dump($i);
}
```

**Note: The amount of values in $array1 and $array2 are the same. So counting 1 array and using it in the for will work for both**

I try to use `$array1[$i]` and `$array2[$i]` in the `for` but when I use that, I get the error.

So the results of the var_dump are:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "value1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "value2"
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "value1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "value2"
}

int(0)
int(1)
```

The error comes from: `var_dump($array2[$i]);`

The way I get the array:

```
$array2=array_values(Input::get('array2'));
```

and the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array2[]" value="value">
```

What is *undefined* here? To my understanding,`$array2[$i]` should work right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the code that makes the error too

Comment: @Phate01 I just `var_dump($array1[$i]);` and `var_dump($array2[$i]);` That's where the errors occure

Comment: Where do you do that `var_dump($array1[$i]);`  ?
You shouldn't use `var_dump($array2[]);`, instead use only like your first example `var_dump($array2);`

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the code that generates the arrays, would you?

Comment: Please, use `var_export` instead of `var_dump`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck It comes out of a checkbox and select box. So it's users input

Comment: Please put `var_dump($array1[$i]);` and `var_dump($array1[$i]);` inside the for, execute and post the whole error you get

Comment: @lmarcelocc I use it inside the for loop and I need to use the `$array2[$i]` in my code in the future

Comment: Also, please place code that produces error.

Comment: @Phate01 I am doing that. I get the undefined offset on the: `var_dump($array2[$i]);`

Comment: @Loko, here it's all working fine. You shoud update your post with your full code.

Comment: Then please show us the output of `var_export($array2);` inside the question; the form code itself may come in handy as well.

Comment: @Ja͢ck 

array (
  0 =&gt; 'value',
  1 =&gt; 'value',
)

Comment: @lmarcelocc The values of the `$array1` and `$array2` are way too complicated and unnecessary to post here. It's user input from checkboxes and select boxes.

Comment: The evidence thus far seems to suggest that the actual values of your arrays *are* necessary; otherwise this question will likely be closed as OT.

Comment: @Ja͢ck The values are var dumped from the arrays? I'll post it and prove you wrong that the way I get the values, has nothing to do with the error. ( I hope)

Comment: After taking into account your question updates, [this](https://eval.in/294939) is the result I get; no errors, expected values.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Must be something on my end then. Should I delete the question? This question wont help anyone in the future, since there isn't anything wrong with the code I provided

Comment: From the small bits of information you've given I was able to distill a few issues that may have caused what you're seeing; posted an answer.

Comment: @Loko would you do this for me, put `$array2[0]` right after `var_dump($array2);` do you get the same error?

Answer (score -2):

you can just do

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if (isset($array2[$key])){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```